# SSDT is not throwing compilation error on unresolved references

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-data-tools

I have recently migrated an existing database to SQL Server SSDT project. After migration it was throwing compilation error (SQL71561) in some views where it was referencing other databases. I have resolved them by adding Database Reference and replaced usage of database with [$(database)] within stored procedure/views.

However, I have noticed there are still some existing references of other databases in stored procedures (or functions/stored procedures) and SSDT is not throwing compilation error for them, instead I can see there is a warning for it.

> Warning       SQL71562: Function: [dbo].[function_name] contains an
>   unresolved reference to an object. Either the object does not exist or
>   the reference is ambiguous because it could refer to any of the
>   following objects.

What does it throw a warning instead of error in this case? i.e. why does it throw error for some stored procedures but warning for others?

Edit: Is it because views are strictly typed and stored procedures are not.

Comment: It partially mimics T-SQL's behavior for that grand misfeature known as deferred compilation. `CREATE PROCEDURE p AS SELECT * FROM foo` is not an error even if there is no `foo` (and in T-SQL it's not even a warning), but `CREATE VIEW v AS SELECT * FROM foo` is.

Comment: Yes, makes sense now. Thank you so much.